# SQL VIEW Execution Timeout Expired

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization

I am getting timeout issue for my view. But timeout is not consistent, it occurs only sometimes.

When I run the query I didn't notice any issue, I'm not very sure where to look in this case to fix the timeout issue.

ERROR:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Execution Timeout Expired

Here is my view:

```sql
CREATE VIEW view_student 
AS     
    SELECT *      
    FROM Student p WITH (NOLOCK, FORCESEEK)      
    WHERE trantype = 23      
      AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 't' FROM attachments m (nolock) 
                      WHERE m.tranid = p.tranid)          
      AND 1 = (CASE 
                  WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 'T' FROM person(NOLOCK) c      
                              WHERE c.type IN (32, 33))      
                       AND EXISTS (SELECT 'T' FROM contract(NOLOCK) co      
                                   WHERE co.TransactionNumber = p.tranid      
                                     AND RIGHT(co.FieldValue, 1) IN (3, 4, 5))      
                     THEN 0    
                     ELSE 1    
               END)
```

Comment: Views don't timeout, that timeout comes from client-side C# code. If you grab the code that your C# client is executing and execute it in SSMS with `SET ARITHABORT ON` does it perform poorly? What does the Actual Execution Plan have to say about it? I imagine you'll see thousands/millions of execution counts on each of your `EXISTS(...)` blocks, so rearranging to code to be smarter about that will probably make it more performant.

Comment: Stop splattering your code with [nolock](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere). If you must use it, AT LEAST use the current syntax and not the deprecated syntax. Don't make more work!

Comment: `SELECT 't'` - Inside an EXISTS clause the content of the row does not matter, only the presence of a row. And you only add confusion by using both upper and lower case letters. And given the code and the various names used, I'll suggest you may have much more significant schema design issues.

Comment: @SMor this is business requirement that's why added nolock.Thanks for useful link about nolock.

Comment: @SMor if i skip the last part that Constant condition then view getting result in fast way. I didn't get either Constant assignment is the cause for slowness?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning i am not a good SQl developer so it hard to read Execution plan for me. do you have any resource send me that help me to read Execution Plan

Comment: show us the query plan by using [Paste the Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/)  and attach the link to your question

Comment: @sal are you sure that is the query plan related to that view , I see the query is selecting from another view (view_mobile_renewal) in the pasted query plan

Comment: @eshirvana plan is related to actual query but i changed in the tables in question due to privacy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

suggestion to you until you provide the query plan:

1. if you can get rid of `nolock` and other query hints, not a good practice
2. add a non persisted computed column as `RIGHT(co.FieldValue, 1)` and make an index on it.
3. you can change your query to below to simplify the query a little bit , it's not a huge performance improvement though:

```
CREATE VIEW view_student 
    AS     
        SELECT *      
        FROM Student p WITH (NOLOCK, FORCESEEK)      
        WHERE trantype = 23      
          AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 't' FROM attachments m (nolock) 
                          WHERE m.tranid = p.tranid)          
          AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 'T' FROM person(NOLOCK) c      
                                  WHERE c.type IN (32, 33))      
          AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 'T' FROM contract(NOLOCK) co      
                                       WHERE co.TransactionNumber = p.tranid      
                                         AND RIGHT(co.FieldValue, 1) IN (3, 4, 5))
```

after looking at the [query plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=S1LPudM5P) here is my advice:

1. I see some of the statistics are off and as a result plan shows that you have `spill data` , so you have to work on those to improve, It might be simply be resolved by updating the stats for your tables  , otherwise It not easy to give you an answer here.but try updating your stats on all the tables involved. `UPDATE STATISTICS table_or_indexed_view_name`
2. also update Index stats by Rebuilding them to make sure you have the best stats , you can rebuild them.

start from there and paste here the plan again

Comment: also keep the query simple , If the view is the problem , just do a select from view only with no where clause